# edge.create event not fired in Like box

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-like

I am not able to fire the `edge.create` event in the Like box. However, it works with a normal like button. Is there a restriction?

Here is my coding:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
        <script>
            FB.init({
                appId  : 'ID12456',
                status : true, // check login status
                cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
            });
        </script>

        <p>Like Box:</p>
        <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
        <fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=163685566990893" stream="false"></fb:like-box>

        <br/><br/>

        <script>
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
                alert("Ok");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mabe because you're linking your Facebook JavaScript code (`all.js`) **two times**.

I tried that code on [FB Rell](http://www.fbrell.com/xfbml/fb%3alike-box), and it's working.

```
<h1>Platform like-box Plugin with Defaults</h1>
    <fb:like-box name="platform"></fb:like-box>

    <script>
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
            function(response) {
                alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
            }
        );
    </script>
```

Comment: No, it is still not working in a standalone Html page. I removed the second all.js call. Any other ideas? Have you tried it saving it as a html and testing it?

Comment: Are you able to run the code i posted above? Just copy it to a new .html file and enter an app id. - It does not work for me.

Comment: I can confirm it doesnt work. Does anyone seen a working example in the wild?

Comment: Ok, so it seems that this is a Facebook Bug? Or was anybody able to run this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a known FB bug. See http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/378710432185222/

It seems to work sometimes in some situations and not in others. One solution is to swap in the regular like button instead. If you use the Facebook JS API and an FQL call, you can get access to all the info you need (page name, url, square pic) to recreate a similar looking widget. Not ideal, but it works...